# pointer in a function as a counter of depth of recursion not working

Tags: c, function, pointers, recursion, counter

I am c beginner and trying to get familiar with different concepts.

For easy understanding of my problem I kept the code in one file. Probably there are better ways to solve the tasks, but that is not the point of my question. It is for learning and understanding only. If I conceptionally going totally wrong with my ideas I am thanksful for a push in the right direction though.

I want to double integers in a loop and for every time doubled I want to show the sum of digits. But if the sum of digits is bigger or equal 10 then I want another sum of digits of that value. My idea was to do that in an recursion, which generally works fine.

So besides my main() I have two functions: one to double the value in a loop and one to get the sum of digits (with a recursion).

Due to the fact that I can only return one value and I think using a static in the recursion is not so nice because I don't want to output it during operation of the function I came to the idea to use a pointer to a counter (depth) instead and handle that over to the function to be able to manipulate the value of the depth counter within every recursion of the function.

after calling the sum of digits functions and handling over the pointer it does not work out. after every printout I wanted to "reset" the variable depth's value to one, but it seems not to work.

Do I place the raising of the pointer wrong?
Or does it not work to call the recursion and the output in the same printf statement?
Who can help me to find out where I am going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int doubleAnInteger(unsigned int input);
unsigned int sumOfDigits(unsigned int input, int *ptr_counter);

unsigned int doubleAnInteger(unsigned int input)
{
    input += input;

    return input;
}

unsigned int sumOfDigits(unsigned int input, int *ptr_counter)
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;

    while (input != 0 )
    {
        sum = sum + input % 10;
        input = input/10;
    }

    if (sum >= 10)
    {
    sum = sumOfDigits(sum, ptr_counter);
    }

    // add 1 to value for variable pointer points to for every recursion
    *ptr_counter = *ptr_counter + 1;
    return sum;
}

void main()
{
    unsigned int i = 1;
    unsigned int doubled = 1;
    int depth = 1; // initializing with 1
    int *ptr_depth = &depth; // set pointer to address of depth

    do
    {
        printf("%d\tDouble: %d\tSum of Digits: %d (depth: %d)\n",i, doubleAnInteger(doubled), sumOfDigits(doubled, ptr_depth), *ptr_depth);
        doubled = doubleAnInteger(doubled);
        i++;
        // reset depth before next loop
        depth = 1;
    }
    while (i <= 30);
}
```

**Output:**

...

4   Double: 16  Sum of Digits: 8 (depth: 1)

5   Double: 32  Sum of Digits: 7 (depth: 1)

6   Double: 64  Sum of Digits: 5 (depth: 1)

7   Double: 128 Sum of Digits: 1 (depth: 1)

8   Double: 256 Sum of Digits: 2 (depth: 1)

9   Double: 512 Sum of Digits: 4 (depth: 1)

10  Double: 1024    Sum of Digits: 8 (depth: 1)

11  Double: 2048    Sum of Digits: 7 (depth: 1)

12  Double: 4096    Sum of Digits: 5 (depth: 1)

13  Double: 8192    Sum of Digits: 1 (depth: 1)

14  Double: 16384   Sum of Digits: 2 (depth: 1)

15  Double: 32768   Sum of Digits: 4 (depth: 1)

16  Double: 65536   Sum of Digits: 8 (depth: 1)

17  Double: 131072  Sum of Digits: 7 (depth: 1)

18  Double: 262144  Sum of Digits: 5 (depth: 1)

19  Double: 524288  Sum of Digits: 1 (depth: 1)

...

depth sould not stay one but be raised by one after 6 or 7 rounds.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the order of evaluation of function arguments is not specified. So when calling `printf()`, it can evaluate `*ptr_depth` before it calls `sumOfDigits()`, which mean you'll get the initial value rather than the updated value.

Call the function outside the arguments to `printf()`.

```
    do
    {
        int sum = sumOfDigits(doubled, ptr_depth);
        printf("%d\tDouble: %d\tSum of Digits: %d (depth: %d)\n",i, doubleAnInteger(doubled), sum, *ptr_depth);
        doubled = doubleAnInteger(doubled);
        i++;
        // reset depth before next loop
        depth = 1;
    }
    while (i <= 30);
```